Difference Between Almost Uniform Convergence and Convergence in Measure
I am using the following definitions for a measure space $(X, \mathscr{P}(X), \mu)$ where $\mathscr{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$. I would like to prove the equivalence of these modes of convergence in the scenario where $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $\mu(\{x\}) > 0$ for all $x \in X$.
A sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges almost uniformly to $f$, if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $E \subseteq X$ with $\mu(E) < \epsilon$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $X \setminus E$.
A sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f$ in measure, if for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$ there is $N(\epsilon, \delta) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $\mu(\{x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta\}) < \epsilon$.
It is clear in the general case that almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure; by writing out the definition of uniform convergence we have that for all $\delta > 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have that $\sup_{x \in X\setminus E}{|f_n(x) - f(x)|} < \delta$. Because we assumed $\mu(E) < \epsilon$ and $E$ is precisely the set in question for the definition of convergence in measure, the desired implication holds.
However, I am struggling with the other direction. I would like to say the following: We have for all $\epsilon, \delta > 0$ the existence of sufficiently large $n$ such that $\mu(\{x \in X : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta\}) < \epsilon$. Calling the set under examination $E$, it seems to me that we have uniform convergence on $X\setminus E$ because $\delta$ is arbitrary. I must however be missing something because this would show equivalence of the two modes of convergence which is not true (to my knowledge, which may be incorrect) in the general case. Comments on the subtlety (or perhaps ignorant oversight depending on perspective) which I am missing would be greatly appreciated.
